# Java: Passing text file in the method paramter

Tags: java, file, filereader

I am trying to make a simple program that can calculate the GPA for any courses that are being currently taken. My issue is that whenever I try to invoke the method by passing the file name of the grades, i get a FILENOTFOUND exception. I checked the path of the file and its in the same directory as my project.

```
static class Grades {
    static void loadGrade(String course, String courseGrade) {
        Object[] courseInfo=null;

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                courseGrade))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                courseInfo = line.split("//s+");
                if (course == courseInfo[0]) {
                    break;
                }

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File was not found");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Grades.loadGrade("Biology", "course_grades");
     }
}
```

this is the error i get:

```
File was not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at gpacalculator.GpaCalculator$Grades.loadGrade(GpaCalculator.java:78)
at gpacalculator.GpaCalculator.main(GpaCalculator.java:106)
```

I ran this in debug mode in Eclipse and it goes straight to the catch block FILENOTFOUND when ran. The null pointer that is thrown is from a for loop that occurs later in the method that cant function because the file cant be found. I just didnt include it for simplicity.

Anyone know how I can tackle this issue? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Forgot to mention explain the format of the text file and the two parameters. The text file is written as

```
Biology    Test 85 Quiz 22 
Math    Test 90 Quiz 50
```

So when I read the the lines and put it in an array, the courseInfo[0] refers to the subject. The two parameters are course(  biology) and courseGrade( the text file). I inserted a break in the while loop so once the line containing the subject is found, the loop terminates.

Comment: You are passing `course_grades`, as the file name. This value doesn't have any folder path and file extension. Make sure that value that you are passing contains correct path and complete file name.

Comment: `if (course == courseInfo[0])` is not the correct way to compare Strings in Java.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java .  Also, I suspect your regular expression is wrong;  you need to be aware of the difference between forward slashes and backslashes.

Comment: @VGR thanks for the tip! I never understood the difference between the two but now I understand a lot better. Thanks!

Comment: @Armaiti So how can i add file path to it? I thought Eclipse would search my directory using the file name.

Comment: @June A running process is not aware of where the files are, you should specify that in your program. Eclipse doesn't search your directories.

Answer (score 1):

When you are building app with Maven or Gradle the output JAR file goes usually in `target/` directory in your project dir. And when you provide relative path to file it **may be** relative to the JAR file being executed (depending on your IDE / launch config).

Option 1: pass full file path.

Option 2: pass path relative to build output directory, for example (but only for testing!) `../course_grades`.